# google web designer environment change

Tags: google-web-designer

I've made a html5 banner with google web designer. As environment i'v choose "Non Google Ad". Now the ad agency would like to have "AdWords"-Banners. Is there a possibility to change the environment on an existed file? I try google but didn't found anything.

thanks for help.

best regards 
thomas

Answer (score 3):

A little bit of a late answer but this is possible:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gwdbeta/OvvG6Kg4P7c/WZYhqCwbZ3kJ

**Non-Google Ad To Adwords/DoubleClick Environment Conversion**

1. Create a new Adwords ad file. This will generate the " gwddoubleclick_min.js" file.
2. Copy the gwddoubleclick_min.js from the New folder you just created  to  the  existing project folder . This is a required file for DoubleClick ad.
3. Open the file in GWD.
4. Switch to Code View.
5. Search for the following lines in the code:

   `<script data-source="gwdgenericad_min.js" data-version="1" data-exports-type="gwd-genericad" type="text/javascript" src="gwdgenericad_min.js"></script>`

   Replace with the following line:

   `<script data-source="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js" data-exports-type="gwd-doubleclick" type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js"></script>`
6. Then, search for the following lines:

   `<gwd-genericad id="gwd-ad">`

   Replace with the following line:

   `<gwd-doubleclick id="gwd-ad" polite-load="">
       <gwd-metric-configuration></gwd-metric-configuration>`
7. Last, search for the following  close tag :

   `</gwd-genericad>`

   And replace it with:

   `</gwd-doubleclick>`
8. Save and reopen the file.
9. Publish the file locally. Then upload to AdWords.

**Adwords/DoubleClick Ads To Non-Google Ad Environment Conversion**

1. Create a new "Non-Google Ad" file. This will generate the "gwdgenericad_min.js" file.
2. Copy the "gwdgenericad_min.js" from the New folder you just created  to the existing project folder of your GWD source html file that you want to convert.
3. Open the file in GWD.
4. Switch to Code View.
5. Find the following line and remove it:

   `<script data-source="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js" data-exports-type="gwd-doubleclick" type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js"></script>`
6. Search for the following lines in the code:

   `<script data-source="gwddoubleclick_min.js" data-version="1.8" data-exports-type="gwd-doubleclick" type="text/javascript" src="gwddoubleclick_min.js"></script>`

   Replace with the following line:

   `<script data-source="gwdgenericad_min.js" data-version="1" data-exports-type="gwd-genericad" type="text/javascript" src="gwdgenericad_min.js"></script>`
7. Find the following tag under `<body>` tag:

   `<gwd-doubleclick id="gwd-ad" polite-load="">
       <gwd-metric-configuration></gwd-metric-configuration>`

   Replace with the following line:

   `<gwd-genericad id="gwd-ad">`
8. Last, search for the following close tag

   `</gwd-doubleclick>`

   And replace it with:

   `</gwd-genericad>`
9. Save and reopen the file.
10. Publish the file locally.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, if anyone needs to just convert from Doubleclick to Adwords (like I did), you don't have to do ANY of the above, just locate this line in the header and update it with the relevant environment.

```
<meta name="environment" content="gwd-adwords">
```

Answer (score 2):

Google has added this option in the latest release of Google Web Designer (Version 3.0.1.0319)

Now you can change the ad environment with the new **File > Ad environment** menu command.

https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/7657416?hl=en&ref_topic=6350071